# ZF3 Translator Remote Loader Factory Unable to resolve service

Tags: php, zend-framework3, zend-translate, zend-servicemanager

I have a problem using MVCTranslator with translations stored in the database.
I configured the translations to use remote_translation, but I can not create a factory for my custom loader.
My files look like this:

**module.config.php**

```
'translator' => [                
    'locale' => 'en_US',
    'translation_file_patterns' => [
        [
            'type'     => 'phparray',
            'base_dir' => getcwd() .  '/data/language',
            'pattern'  => '%s.php',
            'text_domain' => 'default',
        ],             
    ],        
    'remote_translation' => [
        [                
            'type' => Model\DatabaseTranslationLoader::class,
            'text_domain' => 'default',                
        ]
    ],

],
```

**Module.php**

```
namespace MyNamespace;

use Zend\ModuleManager\Feature\ConfigProviderInterface;

class Module implements ConfigProviderInterface
{
    public function getConfig()
    {
        return include __DIR__ . '/../config/module.config.php';
    }

    /*
    ....
    ...
    ....
    */      

    public function getControllerConfig()
    {        
        return [
            'factories' => [
                Controller\MyController::class => function($container) {                   

                    $translator = $container->get('MvcTranslator');                    

                    $translator->getPluginManager()->setFactory(Translator\DatabaseTranslationLoader::class, Factory\DatabaseTranslationLoaderFactory::class); 

                    return new Controller\MyController(
                        $translator
                    );
                },
            ],
        ];
    }

}
```

**Translator\DatabaseTranslationLoader.php**

```
namespace MyNamespace\Translator;

use Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter as DbAdapter;
use Zend\I18n\Translator\Loader\RemoteLoaderInterface;

class DatabaseTranslationLoader implements RemoteLoaderInterface
{
    protected $dbAdapter;

    public function __construct(DbAdapter $adapter)
    {        
        $this->dbAdapter = $adapter;
    }

    public function load($locale, $filename)
    {
        // Database operations
    }
```

**Factory\DatabaseTranslationLoaderFactory.php**

```
namespace MyNamespace\Factory\DatabaseTranslation;

use Interop\Container\ContainerInterface;
use Zend\ServiceManager\Factory\FactoryInterface;   

class DatabaseTranslationLoaderFactory implements FactoryInterface
{       
    public function __invoke(ContainerInterface $container, $requestedName, array $options = null)
    {
        $dbAdapter = $container->get(Zend\Db\Adapter\AdapterInterface:class);           

        return new Translator\DatabaseTranslationLoader($dbAdapter);
    }
}
```

With this configuration, when I try to retrieve database adapter in DatabaseTranslationLoaderFactory receives an exception from the service manager: 
 
    Unable to resolve service "Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter" to a factory; are you certain you provided it during configuration?

It looks like the factory has an empty container (a new ServiceManager instance?).

What am I doing wrong?
Does anyone have any idea how to do this?
I will be grateful for any suggestions.

**EDIT:**

As mentioned above, it looks like this is a new serviceMenager instance in the DatabaseTranslationLoaderFactory.
The same error gets when I try to do:

```
$container->get('router')
```

or

```
$container->get('request')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After hours of searching, I found a solution to my problem.
The explanation of the problem was found in **Zend\I18n\Translator\Translator.php**:

```
public function setPluginManager(LoaderPluginManager $pluginManager)
{
    $this->pluginManager = $pluginManager;

    return $this;
}

public function getPluginManager()
{
    if (! $this->pluginManager instanceof LoaderPluginManager) {
        $this->setPluginManager(new LoaderPluginManager(new ServiceManager));
    }

    return $this->pluginManager;
}
```

From the above, getPluginManager by default creates a new LoaderPluginManager instance with a new instance of ServiceManager.

In my case, to have access to the ServiceManager in the DatabaseTranslationLoaderFactory I had to first use the setPluginManager method, as follows:

**Module.php**

```
namespace MyNamespace;

use Zend\ModuleManager\Feature\ConfigProviderInterface;

class Module implements ConfigProviderInterface
{
    public function getConfig()
    {
        return include __DIR__ . '/../config/module.config.php';
    }

    /*
    ....
    ...
    ....
    */      

    public function getControllerConfig()
    {        
        return [
            'factories' => [
                Controller\MyController::class => function($container) {                   

                    $translator = $container->get('MvcTranslator');  

                    // This line solved my problem
                    $translator->setPluginManager(new \Zend\I18n\Translator\LoaderPluginManager($container));

                    $translator->getPluginManager()->setFactory(Translator\DatabaseTranslationLoader::class, Factory\DatabaseTranslationLoaderFactory::class); 

                    return new Controller\MyController(
                        $translator
                    );
                },
            ],
        ];
    }
}
```

I do not know if this solution is correct, but it works. 
Maybe it will help someone :)

Answer (score 1):

The first, I see you make typo when calling the service. You call variable `$conteiner`. It should be `$container`.

```
$conteiner->get('Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter')
```

**And for retrieving Database Adapter Service use**

```
$container->get(Zend\Db\Adapter\AdapterInterface::class);
```

**instead of**

```
$container->get('Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter')
```

Comment: Thank you for the remarks.
I've included your suggestions, but I still have the same error.
Do you have any ideas yet? My ideas have already exhausted: /

Comment: How about your `db` configuration? have you configure it?

Comment: Yes, I have configured the connection parameters to the database and I am sure this is fine because it uses them in another factory.
Generally speaking, I can not use any service in this factory. The point is that for this factory to work I had to add it by:
`$translator->getPluginManager ()->setFactory(Translator\DatabaseTranslationLoader:: class, Factory\DatabaseTranslationLoaderFactory::class)`
Otherwise it did not work. Maybe there is something wrong? Maybe I should do it a little differently?